# Loop through a collection of objects in an API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, loops, object

I am trying to loop through a collection of entries in this API: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/ID
to list the name of players with ID`s of 8477000 to 8477500. My problem is i'm unsure on how to access loop through the IDs.

Here's my code:

```
function App() {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [player, setPlayer] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
const fetchTiers = async () => {
  await fetch("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8477000/")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => setPlayer(res))
    .then(() => setLoading(false))
    .catch((err) => setLoading(err));
 };
 fetchTiers();
}, []);

const fullname = player ? player.people[0].fullName : "";
return <div className="App">{loading ? "Loading...." : fullname}</div>;
}
```

How can i loop through the player's ID if it must be specified inside the API link?

I tried doing

```
fetch("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/")
//add a random number between 0 and 500
const rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 0);
```

then

```
player.people.rand.fullName
```

But not working.
I'm not understanding how to go about doing this.

Comment: For starters do api docs allow more than one player id submitted?

Comment: What are the range for the IDs that you are getting from API?

Comment: I displayed above. Its 8477000 to 8477500

Comment: @charlietfl im not sure how can i find out?
here's the api doc: https://github.com/dword4/nhlapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is approach that builds an array of request promises based on the start and end ID to set the array length.

Then you use `Promise.all()` to return the full array of player data.

This will require further development for cases where an ID may not return a valid response but gives you a good start point

```js
const getPlayer = id => fetch(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${id}/`)
 .then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>data.people[0]);
 
const getAllPlayers = ( start, end) => {
   const reqPromises = Array.from({length: end-start}, (_, i)=> getPlayer(start +i));
   return Promise.all(reqPromises)
}
 
const start =  8477000, 
      end = start +3;
      
getAllPlayers(start, end).then(players=>console.log(players.map(({fullName})=>fullName)))
```

Comment: how would you modify this to print out the names on the page instead?

Comment: Create a Player component and pass this players array to your Players state then use  `players.map(player=><Player player=={player}/>)` to output list

Answer (score 0):

Try this for creating Dynamic url
Let number = 8477000
If(number<= 'your final limit'){
let url=`yourapi${number}`
await fetch(url)
...
}

Comment: You write if(number<= 'final limit')
how would number ever change from 8477000?

Comment: Please fix formatting. It is hard to read such mixture of regular text and code.

Comment: so i use my random number instead of number i beleive is what you mean?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrovcmon man its sufficiently formatted
And SO doesn't make it easy to frormat also...